# texfield renderer to show number format

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6, sencha-architect, extjs6-classic

I have a form with a textfield and it has a trigger to search on the text entered.
I want to allow the user to type only numbers in it and allow the user to type the entire amount he wants to and when the user completes typing render it to number format(0.000000). Just like how we use renderers in grid columns. How can I achieve this in a form.
I tried this way

```
{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            bind: {
                value: {
                    bindTo: '{salesPriceValue}',
                    twoWay: false

                },
                //disabled: '{!customerPartFilled}',
                //disabled: '{disableSalesPrice}',

                mode: '{currentHeader.adjustmentTypeId}',
                readOnly: '{!securityAccessDetailForm}',
                hideTrigger: '{hideSalesTrigger}'
            },
            fieldLabel: 'Sales Price',
            reference: 'salesPrice',
           // maskRe: /[0-9.-]/,
            regex: /^\-*\d+(\.\d{1,6})?$/,
            flex: 1,
           // hideTrigger: true,
            checkChangeBuffer: 550,
            checkChangeEvents: ['keyup'],
            setMode: function(mode) {
                FACTT.app.setComponentMode(this, mode);
            },
            listeners: {
                change: 'onSellingPriceChange'
            },
            triggers: {
                mytrigger: {
                    handler: 'onSellingPriceLookup',
                    cls: 'x-form-search-trigger'
                }
            }
        in view model
        salesPriceValue: {
        bind: {
            Price: '{currentDetail.salesPrice}'
        },
        get: function(data) {

            if(Ext.isEmpty(data.Price) || data.Price === 0 ){
                return Ext.util.Format.number(data.Price, "0.000000");
            }
            else{
                return data.Price;
            }
           // return Ext.util.Format.number(data.Price, "0.000000");
        }
    }
```

But I am unable to show it in the number format if the user enters 30.

Comment: Can you share some running code in fiddle ?

Comment: Fiddle link: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/27n1

Comment: For above fiddle can you explain what has to be done. I am not getting by reading question.

Comment: the field should allow the user to type whatever format he wants to but while displaying it it should return it in the number format.

Comment: Please give steps how to reproduce same i.e. where to type ,where it will displayed.